# django check the data in the fields if exists in another objects

Tags: python, django

I have some wonders if i can make an object with django and this object contains special fields which no other object can have :

In my situation i have passengers ,flight , chair classes and i need the passenger can have only one chair in flight and chair can only be booked by one passenger and all related to flight so i can book the chair to anyone in another flight.

in **model.py**

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    passenger_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    passenger_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    passenger_flight = models.ForeignKey(Flight ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    passenger_chair = models.ForeignKey(Chair, on_delete=models.CASCADE

class Flight(models.Model):
    flight_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    flight_from = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    flight_to = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aircraft = models.ForeignKey(Aircraft, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    flight_Date = models.DateTimeField()

class Chair(models.Model):
    chair_types = (
        ("Economy", "Economy"),
        ("Business", "Business"))
    chair_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    chair_type = models.CharField(choices=chair_types ,max_length=8)
```

in **view.py**

```
def AddPassengerForm(request):
    form = PassengerTicketForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            if Passenger.objects.filter(
                    passenger_flight=form.cleaned_data["passenger_flight"]) and Passenger.objects.filter(
                    passenger_first_name=form.cleaned_data["passenger_first_name"]) and Passenger.objects.filter(
                    passenger_last_name=form.cleaned_data["passenger_last_name"]):
                print("passenger's chair already booked")
            elif Passenger.objects.filter(
                    passenger_chair=form.cleaned_data["passenger_chair"]) and Passenger.objects.filter(
                    passenger_flight=form.cleaned_data["passenger_flight"]):
                print("chair already booked")
            else:
                form = PassengerTicketForm(request.POST)
                print("thank you for uos")

    context = {
        "pax_ticket_form": form,

    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

this method works very well but i would like to know if there is cleaner or better method to do that.

I appreciate your time.

Comment: You might want to have a look at one to one relationship, here- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: Ganesh Jadhav ,Thank you for valuable reply ,unfortunately if i use onetoone relationship i will not be able to use chair for other passengers in other flights for exampel chair A1 will only be linked to one passenger even the flight is different and the same with flight field onetoone  will make the flight linked to one passenger

Answer (score 0):

You could write your queries in a simpler and cleaner way and you should use `exists()` in order to check if the query exists in the database or not.
Function `exists()` returns `True` if query does exist, otherwise it returns `False`. It's more efficient (simpler and faster execution) to use.
You can read more about this in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#exists).

Here is the way you could refactor your code while using `exists()`:

```
if Passenger.objects.filter(
        passenger_flight=form.cleaned_data["passenger_flight"], 
        passenger_first_name=form.cleaned_data["passenger_first_name"], 
        passenger_last_name=form.cleaned_data["passenger_last_name"])
    .exists():
    print("passenger's chair already booked")
elif Passenger.objects.filter(
        passenger_chair=form.cleaned_data["passenger_chair"], 
        passenger_flight=form.cleaned_data["passenger_flight"])
    .exists():
    print("chair already booked")
else:
    form = PassengerTicketForm(request.POST)
    print("thank you for uos")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, me any one searching for answer appreciate your help .

Comment: Happy to help! If you found the answer helpful please mark it as Accepted answer (Green tick) and/or give it an upvote.